# Ruby questions on def

Tags: ruby, function, block

I am very new to ruby and I would like to understand few syntax.
When I define something like,

```
def attribute
  {
    id:                @object.id,
    password:          @object.password
    non_academic:      !!@object.non_academic
  }.merge(subject)
end
```

what does the codes inside "{}" do, and what are they call. Also, what does line like `id:                @object.id,` means.

Comment: It's Hash literal.

Comment: These questions are about the language of Ruby and for that, referring to the Ruby documentation should be your first place to start. Starting with existing code is ill advised. Refer to rubydocs or the many free ebooks available before attempting to understand code.

Answer (score 1):

It is a method with name `attribute` (`def attribute`) that returns a `Hash` (curly braces ´{}´) with `Symbol`s as keys (`id:`, `password:`, ...). The values are taken from attributes of an instance variable (`@object`)
Then the Hash is also combined with another one (`merge`)